Filter on SEPIC architecture output for making +/- 60 V from 11 V input
I'm working on a LM5155 Boost/Flyback/SEPIC controller reference design PMP40488 from TI. The goal of the design is making variable output (maximum +/- 60 V) from 11 V input. My question is related to the filtering section on the output:

(Image source: PMP40488 schematic from Texas Instruments)
In the filtering part:

If I'm not mistaken, after D1 and D2 there are two PI filters?! I want to know what is the role of R4 and R10 in this circuit?

I see you've already accepted an answer, but there's a detail missing.
the positive voltage is fed back to the feedback pin. Assuming proper regulation, this will never exceed the feedback voltage of 60V (plus maybe some allowed overshoot, if it exists in the control loop).   Yes, the minimum load does help sometimes with the control loop, but I don't believe that is why the 100k resistors are there.
The issue is that this is a dual supply, essentially a SEPIC and Cuk combined in one.
The minimum load helps with "cross regulation" between these two, allowing them to stay reasonably close to one another.  They will still drift, slightly, apart from each other.   Many such regulators (e.g., the "isolated buck" or "flybuck") require a minimum load, otherwise you end up rectifying (w/ D1/D2) switch noise (which can be of untold magnitude but very brief) and generating a much larger (in magnitude) voltage. There isn't much energy in this rectified noise, so the minimum load helps basically bleed away the extra few volts that appear, leaving only the "expected" voltage as coupled by the power converters coupling mechanism (in this case, the coupling capacitor; in the isolated buck I mentioned, the coupled inductors/transformer).
Edit in response to your comment:
The "Test Report: PMP40488" document
(found by going here: https://www.we-online.com/en/components/icref/texas-instruments/LM5155-PMP40488-SEPIC and clicking the "datasheet" link which leads here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidt071b/tidt071b.pdf?ts=1721321036384)
makes a couple references to "cross regulation", see section 2.3.
Notice the table (copied below) that shows how load regulation changes w/ loading.

Notice the VOUT1 is always spot-on; that's because it is the regulated voltage.  Notice VOUT2 varies with load -- as i describe this is only "cross regulated" and not really regulated.
Finally, note that there is a "0mA" column. Well, that's actually a 0.6mA column, since they have a 100k resistor on the 60V output.   If that was truly 0mA, the results would be worse.
So, to answer your comment, I suggest you place both of these resistors, and as a learning exercise try placing or not-placing one or both of them, maybe even play around with values (go higher or lower, e.g. 10k or 1Meg).  And finally, remember that your "load", even when you think it's OFF/zero, may be more than 0.6mA, and if so you don't need any such separate load resistor.

Would you please let me know if I need to put these resistors in my circuit? sometimes my circuit can be without any load and sometimes there will be load, so what is the best strategy? can these resistors effect my load? the maximum power that the circuit can deliver to my load?

@Andromeda, see edit to my answer.  Short version: YES.


I want to know what is the role of R4 and R10 in this circuit?

They are there to provide a light load when no real load is connected. If you didn't have these resistors and you disconnected your load, you might find that the voltage outputs instead of being +/- 60 volts, grew to somewhat larger values. You should probably read the data sheet of the device to see what it says but, what I said above is usually the reason.

Respectfully, I believe this is incomplete and the real answer lies in the cross-regulation of the negative side.   Admittedly a minimum load may help in the control theory, but generally it is not necessary and the regulated output (here, the positive) will have no issue maintaining the setpoint, at least in the steady state.  It is the negative, unregulated rail, that benefits from the minimum loading for a variety of reasons.

I learned that these are just dummy loads on the circuit. I did a simulation on the circuit with the resistor and without:
With the resistor:

Without:

So, it seems we have the same results based on the simulation.
