Circuit analysis for DC-DC convertor SEPIC architecture
I'm analyzing the following reference design from Texas instrument for making a variable dual output (+/-60V form 11V):

What I'm curious to know is to understand the signal waveform for the following simulation:

The waveforms:

What I do not understand is PULESED-WAVE-P and PULESED-WAVE-N, What I expect is the D1 just pass the positive pules (cycles) and D2 just pass negative pules (cycles), but what we see is that they both are passing positive and negative pulse at the same time:
If we zoom in, we can that both have crossed the zero level (Time scale 14.42 ms to 14.46 ms):


Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/719818/filter-on-sepic-architecture-output-for-making-60-v-from-11-v-input

@winny Hi thanks for the comment, yes it is, but this question is a totally different finding in comparison to that question

Ask your self this very important question; what is the long-term average voltage across an inductor equal to?

@Andy aka Hello Andy, thanks for the comment, assume it is zero?

It is and, that means the waveform at node pulsed wave P is totally explainable. With a little more thinking it explains why pulse wave N is also as it is.
